# Bluetooth permission is missing error while i don't need bluetooth

Tags: android, permissions, bluetooth

I am working on SDK that you can add to your app. with every app i attach it i get logcat error :
BLUETOOTH permission is missing!

My sdk doesn't require or doing anything that has any connection to bluetooth and i don't want to add this permission. Does someone have an idea why it happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that somehow, when i ask for the userAgent in my sdk, using: 
WebSettings.getDefaultUserAgent(context)
This bluetooth error pops up. I guess that this function asks for bluetooth data, which can't be acquired without the permission.